# Simple javascript split() working as intended?

Tags: javascript, html

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/4ntjykr0/

```js
var x="pokemon,rykrkr";
x.split(",");
document.getElementById('ok').innerHTML=x[0];
```

```html
<div id="ok"></div>
```

Isn't this supposed to show the whole word "pokemon" because I specified that it would split on comma?

Comment: `x` is not the splitted string. You don't store it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`.split` doesn't alter the original string, so you have to do it like this:

```js
var x = "pokemon,rykrkr";
var splited = x.split(",");

document.getElementById('ok').innerHTML = splited[0];
```

```html
<div id="ok"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x="pokemon,rykrkr";
y=x.split(",");

document.getElementById('ok').innerHTML=y[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the first character of `pokemon,rykrkr`, you are displaying, but you need the splitted words.

```js
var x = "pokemon,rykrkr",
    words = x.split(",");

document.getElementById('ok').innerHTML = words[0];
```

```html
<div id="ok"></div>
```